# Google Sheet Array Formula with an If statement

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to populate one sheet with data from another based on one column using an array formula.

My Data (simplified sample) looks like this:

[image]

I know I can merge the data together with this formula.

```
=unique({(B6:D);(F6:H)})
```

But I only to pull the rows that have refund in the 3rd column.

I've done some googling and managed to come up with this:

```
=unique({(if(D6:D='Refund',B6:D);(if(H6:D='Refund',F6:H)})))
```

But that's not working and I can't figure out how to do this.
I've seen some entries that mention using the filter function but that didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`=query(unique({(B6:D);(F6:H)}),"where Col3 contains 'Refund' ",0)`

Comment: that worked perfectly thanks!
haven't used query functions before, will need to read up on them

Comment: They're really powerful. The best start is to look here:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#language-clauses

If you wanted to order your query above, you'd use:

=query(unique({(B6:D);(F6:H)}),"where Col3 contains 'Refund' order by Col1,Col2 ",0)

Other examples:

=query(unique({(B6:D);(F6:H)}),"where Col1 is not null and Col3 contains 'Refund' order by Col1,Col2 label Col1 'Name1',Col2 'Name2'  ",0)

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting
they kind of work like sql queries